# How to fix bad conflict resolution in the middle of a big git rebase?

Tags: git, egit, git-rebase

I’m trying to rebase a feature branch with a lot (~300) of commits onto a newer major release version of the base product. Right in the middle of the rebase with many conflicts already resolved, I notice that some files still contain conflict markers (“<<<<<<<”), even though no more conflicting files are listed in `git status`. I guess that I missed them in some earlier commit, mistakenly marking the files as resolved, even though they weren’t.

Is there a way to fix mistakes in earlier commits in the middle of an ongoing rebase, and continuing the rebase afterwards?

I don’t want to `--abort` the rebase, because I would lose many hours of conflict resolution work.

I don’t want to ignore the problem, by just fixing the conflict markers in the commit I’m currently in. This way the intermediate commits would be invalid and non-compiling.

I have already made a backup copy of my working directory, so I can experiment.

If there’s no easier way, my backup plan would be to finish the rebase as it is and try to clean up the history afterwards. I would remove the conflict markers in the current commit and note its ID. After the rebase is finished, I would try to find the earlier commits which introduced the conflict markers with some pickaxe magic and then try to clean up the history in another `git rebase -i`. Do you think this route is feasible?

I’ve used Eclipse egit so far, in case it matters, but would switch to the commandline for advanced stuff.

Comment: you could finish the rebase, then 'git bisect' to the first commit with the conflict markers. fix it , then 'git rebase --onto=FIXEDCOMMIT' it